# Como atualizar o @angular/core globalmente?

Tags: angular, npm

Eu fiz a atualização do **angular/cli** para a ultima versão (*Angular 8*), mas quando eu crio um projeto novo, o `@angular/core` está na versão **`@7.2.15`** e não na versão **`@8.1.0`**.

O projeto dá erro se eu tento compilar o projeto com o `ng serve`. 
Para que funcione, eu preciso atualizar o `@angular/core` toda vez logo após que crio um projeto. 
Então eu gostaria de criar os meus projetos já com a versão do core do angular na versão **`@8.1.0`**, para que eu não precise ficar dando o comando `ng update @angular/core` toda vez que eu criar um projeto.
 
Porque quando eu utilizava o angular na versão anterior, eu não precisava disso.

Existe uma maneira de atualizar o `@angular/core` de forma **global**?

Answer (score 0):

[Esse link](https://medium.com/@pliniopjn/angular-6-atualizando-um-projeto-existente-a783e23e5b0d) pode lhe ajudar, caso esteja usando o `npm`

Aplicando algumas alterações

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@8.1.0
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver. Eu só precisava reiniciar o computador para ele começa a criar o projeto na versão atual.